# Use substitute() to replace a label/argument name

Tags: r, eval, substitution

I have the following code:

```
eval(substitute(list(x = y), list(x = "foo", y = "bar")))
```

This returns `list(x = "bar")`, i.e. only the value gets substituted but not the label.

How do I make `substitute()` replace the label too so that the result is `list(foo = "bar")`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x` is bound to a name.  We can see that with

```
as.list(substitute(list(x = y)))
# [[1]]
# list
#
# $x
# y
```

So it's not terribly easy to change the name within the `substitute` call.  But you can do

```
e <- substitute(list(x = y), list(y = "bar"))
names(e)[2] <- "foo"
eval(e)
# $foo
# [1] "bar"
```

or with just `substitute` you can change the expression to use `setNames`

```
e <- substitute(setNames(list(y), x), list(x = "foo", y = "bar"))
eval(e)
# $foo
# [1] "bar"
```

But you can also use `call`, which is easier

```
cl <- call("list", foo = "bar")
eval(cl)
# $foo
# [1] "bar"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for pointing out various approaches. Unfortunately, neither makes me 100% happy. I was rather looking for a generic solution which works for other expressions too (not just lists). Also the value of x is a string, which is why using `call()` doesn't work, since it presupposes the construction of an argument list that should be the result of whole thing. I get the impression that a two-step approach similar to examples #2 & #3 is the preferable approach. I was hoping there were a one-stop solution with `substitute()` and friends.

Comment: @lith - the `setNames` code in the middle won't work for you?

Comment: Well, I'm beginning to like `setNames()` since it can be used in conjunction with `do.call()` to solve the original problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this monster:

eval(parse(text=eval(substitute(paste0("list(",x," = \"",y,"\")"),list(x="foo",y="bar")))))

Comment: Thanks for your "monster". :-) I would like to avoid string munging though.